# How to place popover posistion button bottom and start from button left edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have placed button in my application .If user press the button need to show popover button bottom and start from button left edge

I have used data-placement="auto left" it is not working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Content">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Content">Bottom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement=" auto left" data-content="Content">Left</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Content">Right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks
vijay

Comment: Can you post your runnable code snippet here? That would be easy to debug

Comment: it is in left side..left corner to right means?

Comment: @BhumiShah from hyperlink it should start left  and it should end in right and display in bottom